How do I import an SVG as one path object instead of many?
When I import my svg file, that I created in Inkscape, every shape in that file gets turned into its own path object, rather than one path object with all my shapes, as seen in the Outliner:

This is my artwork:

How do I get it to import such that all the paths are in one path? I wanted to apply modifications through geometry nodes and its quite tedious to do for each path.
Other than that, the import has no other issues.
This is what happens if I try to join them with Ctrl+J:


You can't just join em with Ctrl+J?

It affects the final result, here is the original after import:
Before
Here is what happens if join them with Ctrl+J:
After

Please edit your original question and insert the images directly into it using the built-in tools rather than putting links in comments. Thanks.

Perhaps you should try converting them to meshes before joining.

Apart from converting it to a mesh before joining, when they all lay in the same plane (i.e. have the exact same Z location) you would get problems with Z fighting anyway... but the only problem seems to be the circle around it. What about joining all other objects except for the circle...? But if you want to keep different colors for each part, you cannot join them anyway or have to convert them to mesh, because a curve object can only have one material.

As far as i know, you can't. Blender imports the paths that you have as they are. if you have 5, you will get 5 paths and so. What you can do as other mentioned, is to conver every path to mesh (Object menu > Convert > Mesh) and then join them all (CTRL + J)

@Emir This video seems to contradict your statement. The logo he imported shows up with the paths in multiple groups. If it worked as you said, then we'd be seeing ~40 paths separately in his Outliner. How come?

@IanDanielSooknanan you didn't understand what I meant. Multiple objects doesn't mean multiple paths; three circles could be one path or three paths, that might depend on the way you make your svg. Blender is not your issue. Your issue is how you make your File

Here is a visual representation https://imgur.com/a/cMKYZfj If you build your logo and let the paths as indivual ones, Blender will get them as individual curves. if on the other hand you make one path out of all your design, then Blender will get one path

@Emir Thank you, I see what you mean. Did you use "combine" in Inkscape to join the circles in the red example?

It looks like some or all of the bad effect from joining is connected to that one complete circle that borders most of the drawing and doesn’t have any width. I recommend you delete it, then try joining.

This looks more like a good comment, than an answer

@Emir It it is both an answer and a comment, until he tries the suggestion. I’m a cat, trust me.

@Emir what I mean is that I am pretty sure this is the exact problem. The circle is causing the drawing logic for the SVG to get all messed up, and deleting it should fix the problem. If it does, then this is the answer. If it doesn’t, then this was more of a comment suggestion (or at least an incorrect answer).
